# Radio buttons don't show

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jradiobutton

I am trying to make survey in java. I have 20 questions and 5 possible choices. I was thinking of making 20 labels and 100 radio buttons grouped by 5.

I managed to manually add labels using the Net beans GUI, but I wanted to generate buttons, but they don't show. Here is my code:

```
public class Prikaz extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Prikaz
     */
    public Prikaz() {
        initComponents();
        javax.swing.JRadioButton [][] buttons = new javax.swing.JRadioButton [20][5];
        ButtonGroup [] bg = new ButtonGroup[20];


        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            bg[i]= new ButtonGroup();
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
                buttons[i][j] = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
                if(j==0)buttons[i][j].setSelected(true);
                buttons[i][j].setLocation(1014+(j*24) , 44+(i*31));
                buttons[i][j].setToolTipText(((Integer)(j+1)).toString());
                buttons[i][j].setVisible(true);
                buttons[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                bg[i].add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel16;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel17;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel18;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel19;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel20;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel21;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: don't you need to add the buttongroup to a form or panel?

Comment: I have tried adding them to the new panel and to the label, but they don't show either way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the buttons to the parent component in addition to the ButtonGroup.

For example, to add the button to `jlabel1`, add this after creating the button:

`jlabel1.add(buttons[i][j]);`

Edit:
If it doesn't work, first do `jLabel.setLayout(new FlowLayout())` for each `JLabel`, then add new button.

Comment: Did you add the labels to the frame?

Comment: I'm also skeptical about your `setLocation()` method. I personally would use a `GridLayout`.

Comment: I did add labels to the frame, they are shown, so I don't understand what is wrong, I also tried to remove the setLocation() and then add it to jlabel, still no luck

Comment: What layout do the JLabels have?

Comment: its internally generated I think

Comment: You'll need to specifically add one. Try a `FlowLayout` first, just do `jlabel.setLayout(new FlowLayout())` for each JLabel

Comment: @Frakcool If you look more closely at the code, it makes a group for a set of 5 buttons. So you can only select 1 answer per label(question).